# Deploying Java projects to other users

Tags: java, swing, jframe, javac, japplet

I am new to Java and is using Eclipse.

Whenever I have build a Java (JFrame) project successfully on my PC and when I deploy the java project files to other users, I have to compile the projects on other ppl's PC before they can really use it.

Is there any convenient way to tackle this? i.e. When I placed those Java files to a shared folder, all other users (new/existing) can execute it on their PC.. (juz like .exe in MS Window) Actually how is the practice outside?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to distribute a desktop app. to users is [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It requires some extra work from us the developer, but is a breeze for the end user.

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Comment: @Tsui John: Even if you also deploy enhanced, platform-specific packages, [tag:javawebstart] is an excellent baseline; I've never looked back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eclipse to create a JAR file for your project, and it will generate an executable JAR that the others can run. For more on creating JARs in Eclipse, see [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-32.htm&resultof=%22jar%22%20).